# Integral from $y$ to $\infty$ of $1(Y>y) = y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

I'm trying to figure out something but I can't seem to get it.

**My professor wrote in the notes relative to E[Y] =  $\int_{0}^{\infty}$P(Y>y) if Y is a takes non-negative values:**

Let the indicator function be := $1_B(x)$ = $1$ if $x\in B$ and 0therwise for B a borel set.

Then, let $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the random variable with density function $1_B(y)$

It implies that

P{Y>y} = $\int_{0}^{\infty} 1_{Y>y}(y) dy = y$

I'm trying to find sense to that. Because from what I understand, it's the probability that $y>y$ which kind of never happens. But if I change say $x$ instead of y for one of them. Then when $x$ reaches $y$, we get

$\int_{x}^{\infty} 1dy$ = y????

Anyway, if anyone could help me make some sense to that, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: "let $Y$ be the random variable with density function $1_B(y)$" What is $B$ here, and why does it not appear in the rest of your post?

Comment: B is any measurable subset of the real numbers

Comment: Did your professor mention Fubini's theorem?

Comment: The assertion that "P{Y>y} = $\int_{0}^{\infty} 1_{Y<y}(y) dy = y$" is wrong in general.

Comment: $\mathbf 1_B(y)$ is *not* a probability density function, *except* when $\int_B \mathsf d x=1$.

Comment: Where do you see the probability that $y\gt y$?

Comment: The assertion that, when $P(Y\geqslant0)=1$, $$E(Y)=\int_0^\infty P(Y>y)dy$$ (please note the difference with what you write in your question) has been asked about and proved several times on the site. It follows in full generality from the pointwise identity $$Y=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{Y>y}dy$$ from Tonelli theorem (aka Fubini for nonnegative functions), and from the fact that, for every event $A$, $$E(\mathbf 1_A)=P(A)$$

Comment: Yes thank you I miswrote it's Y>y

Comment: Not the point. Actually, one can replace each $Y>y$ by $Y\geqslant y$ in my comment.